# solr geography hierarchy

Tags: solr, hierarchy, facet

I've been trying to figure out a way to implement faceting with hierarchies in solr and can't figure out how to do it in my situation.  I've read a couple of the articles on doing hierarchies in solr along with the solutions in patch 64 and 792.  The main issue I'm having is that I have entities that can belong to multiple branches of the hierarchy.  The current form of my data is a user document with MVAs for country, state, and city.

Take for instance a geographical hierarchy that people can list their services for down to a city level.  A person may service all of alabama but only certain towns in georgia.  Now the faceting count for the state level counts the distinct individuals that service an area which is a 1 for alabama and a 1 for georgia and when expanded down to the city level has a count for each city (in other words the sum of the city counts won't necessarily equal the state count since the counts are not mutually exclusive).

> US(1)
>
> > Georgia(1)
> >
> > > Atlanta(1)
> > > Columbus(0)
> > > Athens(0)
> >
> > Alabama(1)
> >
> > > Mobile(1)
> > > Birmingham(1)
> > > Huntsville(1)

The part I'm getting hung up on is when faceting on the cities I have no way of knowing what state they belong to since the user is listed in both alabama and georgia and I can't figure out a way to relate attributes to each other.  solr-64 might work if it supports multiple branches like US/Alabama/Mobile/ and US/Georgia/Atlanta/ for the same document. As of right now I havent been able to get it to compile with the nightly build though so I'm kind of stuck.

Does anyone have a better way of doing this?

Comment: To clarify, do you have a document per city, or a single document per service that lists all cities and states within the document?

Comment: All of the suggestions work fine with the user only belonging to 1 branch.  What's happening is if I issue the query for facet.field=city then the cities for both states show up with no way of grouping them according to their parent state.  Even if I pivot or group, it thinks that all the cities belong to each state.  If I put a delimiter in like rfreak suggested I can reconstruct the tree but it seems to require a lot of client side processing because it won't automatically roll up the counts to the state level.

Answer (score 2):

See the first use case described [here](http://karussell.wordpress.com/2010/12/08/use-cases-of-faceted-search-for-apache-solr/). (client side processing for indexing and querying necessary!)

**Category navigation**

The problem: you have a tree of categories and your products are categorized in multiple of those categories.

There are two relative similar solutions for this problem. I will describe one of them:

- Create a multivalued string field called ‘category’. Use the category id (or name if you want to avoid DB queries).
- You have a category tree. Make sure a document gets not only the leaf category, but all categories until the root node.
- Now facet over the category field with ‘-1′ as limit
- But what if you want to display only the categories of one level? E.g. if you don’t want other level at a time or if they are too much.

  Then index the category field ala `<level>_category`. For that you will need the complete category tree in RAM while indexing. Then use `facet.prefix=<level>_` to filter the category list for the level
- Clicking on a category entry should result in a filter query ala `fq=category:”<level>_categoryId”`
- The little tricky part is now that your UI or middle tier has to parse the level e.g. 2 and the append 2+1=3 to the query: facet.prefix=3_
- If you filter the level then one question remains:

  Q: how can you display the path from the selected category until the root category?

  A: Either get the category parents via DB, which is easy if you store the category ids in Solr – not the category names.
    Or get the parents from the parameter list which is a bit more complicated but doable. In this case you’ll need to store the category names in Solr.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying, I was doing something similar before I broke out the levels into different fields.  What happens when a product is in more than one category and you want to facet on the leaves but constrain it to only 1 branch?  I can't find a solution that will give me the enumeration and counts without including the leaves from the other branch.  I can store it as id values and go back to the db to look up the parent category to filter out the unwanted leaves but that also means that I have to handle the counts on the client side.  Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: we are always displaying the root first (e.g. films, books, ...). Then the user sees in which branches he can get into.

Comment: (one layout problem: in the post the level_category thing was removed. updated)

Comment: what do you mean with 'I have to handle the counts on the client side.'?

Comment: Regarding "facet on the leaves but constrain it to only 1 branch" -> you are faceting on level_categoryId this way you are filtering out all other branches. Or what did you mean?

Answer (score 1):

I am not that familiar with your problem but it seems you need to do a group-by city,state.

Have a look at the group-by feature in SOLR called field collapsing (http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing).

Also, have a look at bobo-browse as well. Specifically, compositeFacetHandlers http://code.google.com/p/bobo-browse/wiki/CompositeFacetHandlers. bobo-browse can be integrated into SOLR (http://code.google.com/p/bobo-browse/wiki/SolrIntegration)

Answer (score 1):

Check out Pivot (i.e. Decision Tree) Faceting: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#Pivot_.28ie_Decision_Tree.29_Faceting

It is supported in Solr 4.0

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your documents in the index represent a single service....

For the city, manufacture a field that is the state concatenated with the city using a delimiter of some sort. This field doesn't have to ever be displayed to the user, it can be in addition to a field you store but don't index that is the real name of the city.

For example you could have a city_facet field with values of:

- "Ohio - Miami"
- "Florida - Miami"

You probably want to pick a delimiter that is safer. I imagine a hyphen could be a potential conflict.